# Maven - exclude folder from build

Tags: maven, maven-compiler-plugin

Trying to exlcude a folder `src/main/resources/scripts/` from my build but the following does not work:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>src/main/resources/scripts/</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>src/main/resources/scripts/</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Instead try:

```
<exclude>scripts/**</exclude>
```

The exclude is based on directory, so your construction would exclude

```
src/main/resources/src/main/resources/scripts
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Did you do a `mvn clean` first? Btw, it has no effect on the manven-compiler-plugin, which only compiles .java files. The maven-resources-plugin is responsible for copying these files to the classpath.

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html gives you proper examples. `**` only matches the directories, in case of files, I'd expect it to be `scripts/**/*`

Comment: Again, no joy. I am doing a `mvn clean`, then a `mvn compile`.

Comment: please execute `mvn clean process-resources -X` and pastebin.com the results?

Comment: You're going to think I am an idiot...I was looking at the wrong project entirely...your suggestion works. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem and found the following issues:

- You may have a parent pom which already defines a configuration for the `maven-compiler-plugin`. For this, add `combine.self="override"` to the `configuration` tag. See [Maven : Is it possible to override the configuration of a plugin already defined for a profile in a parent POM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771561/maven-is-it-possible-to-override-the-configuration-of-a-plugin-already-defined)
- It seems the plugin ignores excludes if it needs the excluded classes for the compilation: make sure you are not referencing the excluded classes from other classes which will get compiled. For example, if you exclude `Foo.java`, but in `Bar.java` you `import Foo;` it will (try to) compile `Foo.java` to compile `Bar.java`.

For example:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>myId</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration combine.self="override">
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/some/full/directory/*</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/some/single/File.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
</profile>
```

Comment: Single file excluding didn't work for me with version 3.6.0

Comment: This gives a build error on current versions of maven and the plugin

Comment: My pom had no `excludes` node.  In this answer It was helpful to see the snippet in context.

Answer (score 7):

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>readBuild</id>
        <build>
             <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration >
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/com/pyramid/controllers/EntitlementWriteController.java</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/com/pyramid/controllers/ProductWriteController.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                     <testExcludes>
                      <testExclude>**/com/pyramid/controllers/EntitlementWriteControllerTest.java</testExclude>
                       <testExclude>**/com/pyramid/controllers/ProductWriteControllerTest.java</testExclude>
                    </testExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
            <directory>yourDirectory</directory>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Comment: After reading a questions with 40+ votes finally I found a working one (The Kumar) ! Thank you !

Answer (score 6):

It's so very simple and you not need add other plugin:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

```
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>application.properties</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
```

Comment: Sorry, you completely misunderstood what question was about..

Comment: i have two up votes

Comment: This should actually be the correct and accepted answer. If you want to exclude folders/ files from the resources folder, you use the maven-resources-plugin for this. See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html for a full reference.