# Maven exclude folder not working

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

My pom file has code something like below:
Where I need that  should exclude generating given files at the time of building project while 
 should exclude generating the given folder (including all subfolders & files) itself while building project.

```xml
<profile>
    <id>nets</id>
    <properties>
        <ulysses.menu>ldms-menu.properties</ulysses.menu>
        <approval.workflow>false</approval.workflow>
        <mail.useldap>false</mail.useldap>
        <mail.latize.usesmtp>false</mail.latize.usesmtp>
        <ulysses.base.uri>http://data.latize.com/nets</ulysses.base.uri>
        <!-- lee.menu>nets-menu.properties</lee.menu >
        <lee.ftl>nets.ftl</lee.ftl>
        <path.has.lee>nets</path.has.lee>
        <kiwi.pages.startup>core/nets/summary.html</kiwi.pages.startup>
        <project.exclude.core.files>**/marmotta/platform/core/services/triplestore/*SesameServiceImpl*.*</project.exclude.core.files-->
        <project.exclude.core.files>**/ihg*.*</project.exclude.core.files>
        <project.exclude.core.folder>**/web/ihg/**</project.exclude.core.folder>
    </properties>
</profile>

...
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <!--excludes native sesame implementation-->
                    <!--exclude>**/PrimarySesameServiceImpl*.*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/ApprovalSesameServiceImpl*.*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/SesameServiceImpl*.*</exclude-->

                    <!--excludes GraphDB sesame implementation -->
                    <!--exclude>**/GraphDBPrimarySesameServiceImpl*.*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/GraphDBApprovalSesameServiceImpl*.*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/GraphDBSesameServiceImpl*.*</exclude-->

                    <exclude>${project.exclude.core.files}</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <resource>
                    <directory>${project.exclude.core.folder}</directory>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>*.*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </resource>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Here file exclusion starting from ihg is working, but folder ihg is not getting excluded. I have no idea how can I exclude folder in this case.

Comment: iirc, `project.exclude.core.folders` are not built-in properties in Maven.  You should show us how you are using these properties.

Comment: @AdrianShum: In this case, how can I exclude folder in my code hierarchy? I am new to POM

Comment: What do you mean by "exclude"? Excluding from Java compiler? Excluding from resource bundling? be specific please.  In brief, try to understand which plugin is dealing with your source code you want to exclude, and find answer from its project page

Comment: @AdrianShum: I just don't want to create those files at the time of building my project

Comment: Can you try to read the comments again? You are missing the most important point.  No one know how to exclude unless you give information on what are those source code.

Comment: @AdrianShum: Hi, sry. I have provided much clearer details. Please let me know if still something is missing.

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html  There seems no configuration for `resource`.  Can you make sure you have the correct config? And, it will be good if you can give some info on the related directory structure and what you are trying to include/exclude

Comment: Make separate modules in maven to make a separation of concern. Implementations should be separated from interfaces. Furthermore why are you trying to create a `test-jar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer: [Maven - exclude folder from build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25262794/maven-exclude-folder-from-build)

In short

Try

`<exclude>**/foo/**</exclude>`

It will EXCLUDE foo as a folder

Answer (score 2):

Have had a brief try in `maven-jar-plugin`.  Assume I have something like this:

```
foo-proj
  + src
    + main
      + resources
        + foo
          - foo.txt
        + bar
          - bar.txt
```

I can exclude `foo` from the result jar by:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/foo/**</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: if you simply want to exclude from your final jar, you do not need to "call" anything.  `maven-jar-plugin` is bound to the lifecycle by default.  Here you just need to provide configurations as demonstrated here.

Comment: It is not about DELETING.  It is simply excluded from the result JAR.

Comment: I think there are subdirectories under the one you are excluding.  Check the update

Comment: Now already correct answer is posted dear. By the way Thanks for your time.