# Maven-compiler-plugin excluding fails in 3.3

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

### I used this in maven-compiler-plugin 3.2 and it worked fine, but when I upgraded to 3.3 excludes doesn't longer work. What changed that broke my excluding?

**Situation:**

[image: Packages]

This is a list of my packages. I want to exclude all packages starting with bammerbom.ultimatecore.spongeapi because they are WIP. This worked on maven-compiler-plugin 3.2, but after updating it failes with the stacktrace below. (All errors are there, but it is not a problem because I don't want this packages to be compiled yet.)

**Pom.xml for the plugin:**

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2 (Wanted to update to 3.3)</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>bammerbom/ultimatecore/spongeapi/</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Stacktrace:**

http://pastebin.com/zp8UqRiB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting some wildcards at the end

```
<excludes>
    <exclude>bammerbom/ultimatecore/spongeapi/**</exclude>
</excludes>
```

[Maven - exclude folder from build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25262794/maven-exclude-folder-from-build)