# Excluding folders/files from specific folder in pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml

This is what I am doing to exclude **js** folder under `src/main/resources/my-app/component/`. But, it isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

```
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>**/component/js/**/*</exclude>
        <exclude>**/component/js/**</exclude>
        <exclude>**/component/js/*.js</exclude>
        <exclude>**/component/js/**/*.js</exclude>
    </excludes>
</resource>
```

Comment: `<exclude>my-app/component/js/**</exclude>` should work.

Comment: The above question like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25262794/maven-exclude-folder-from-build

Comment: There is a duplicate resource plugin at the end of pom.xml that is including everything inside src/main/resources. Removing that fixed it.