# How to exclude node_modules from maven build

Tags: java, maven

I use Gulp and for this reason Node.js in my project. I have a `node_modules` folder inside `src/main/resources` and every time I run `mvn install` it copies 9000+ Files to the target folder.

I don't want this! How can I exclude the `node_modules` folder?

I tried this:

```
<excludes>
    <exclude>**/src/main/resources/node_modules/*</exclude>
</excludes>
```

and this

```
<excludes>
    <exclude>node_modules/**</exclude>
</excludes>
```

inside configuration tag of the maven-compiler-plugin. But this doesn't work.

Does anyone have solution?

And here is the build part of my pom

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jira-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${amps.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <productVersion>${jira.version}</productVersion>
                <productDataVersion>${jira.version}</productDataVersion>
                <applications>
                    <application>
                        <applicationKey>jira-software</applicationKey>
                        <version>${jira.software.application.version}</version>
                    </application>
                </applications>
                <!-- Uncomment to install TestKit backdoor in JIRA. -->
                <!--
                <pluginArtifacts>
                    <pluginArtifact>
                        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira.tests</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jira-testkit-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${testkit.version}</version>
                    </pluginArtifact>
                </pluginArtifacts>
                -->
                <pluginArtifacts>
                    <pluginArtifact>
                        <groupId>com.atlassian.labs.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>quickreload</artifactId>
                        <version>1.30.5</version>
                    </pluginArtifact>
                </pluginArtifacts>
                <compressResources>false</compressResources>
                <enableQuickReload>true</enableQuickReload>
                <enableFastdev>false</enableFastdev>
                <allowGoogleTracking>false</allowGoogleTracking>
                <productDataPath>./generated-test-resources.zip
                </productDataPath>
                <!-- See here for an explanation of default instructions: -->
                <!-- https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/advanced-topics/configuration-of-instructions-in-atlassian-plugins -->
                <instructions>
                    <Atlassian-Plugin-Key>${atlassian.plugin.key}</Atlassian-Plugin-Key>

                    <!-- Add package to export here -->
                    <Export-Package>
                        de.cschulc.jira.plugin.api,
                    </Export-Package>

                    <!-- Add package import here -->
                    <Import-Package>
                        org.springframework.osgi.*;resolution:="optional",
                        org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.*;resolution:="optional",
                        *;version="0";resolution:=optional,
                        *
                    </Import-Package>

                    <!-- Ensure plugin is spring powered -->
                    <Spring-Context>*</Spring-Context>
                </instructions>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/src/main/resources/node_modules/*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>atlassian-spring-scanner</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <scannedDependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-external-jar</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                </scannedDependencies>
                <verbose>false</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Post your pom.xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven - exclude folder from build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25262794/maven-exclude-folder-from-build)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you a different approach that works fine for me.

1. move node_modules from `myproject/src/main/resources` to `myproject`: when I want to install modules locally it's more natural for me to run npm from the root folder of the project because it's my working dir, see [global vs local](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/)
2. use in your pom this plug-in: [frontend maven plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin), it works great with node and npm to let you use many javascript automation tools. It has a good documentation to make it works.
3. use gulp or grunt to move only the javascript resources you need in the classpath from `myproject/node_modules` to `myproject/target/...`

Comment: Yes I did this solution, because I'm not in mood to search a solution to exclude the node_modules folder.

Answer (score 2):

Instead try:

```
<exclude>node_modules/**</exclude>
```

then try

```
 mvn clean process-resources -X
```

Answer (score 2):

i have this problem，fixed by

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.3</version>
     <configuration>
         <warSourceExcludes>node_modules/**,build/**,config/**,src/**</warSourceExcludes>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```