# Merging plugin configuration from profile

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-profiles

I have a configuration entry for exec-maven-plugin

```
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>compass</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>compile</argument>
                            <argument>-c</argument>
                            <argument>config_production.rb</argument>
                            <argument>--force</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
```

now in a profile I'd like to merge this configuration with:

```
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument>compile</argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </configuration>
```

because `combine.children="merge"` is the default I'd expect the effective configuration to be:

```
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>compass</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>compile</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
```

but instead it's the same as original.

What gives? I've tried setting  `combine.children="merge"` and  `combine.self="override"` to no avail.

[Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html) only mentions "how child POMs inherit configuration from parent POMs", but I'd expect merging from profiles to work the same way.

Above results show that merging from profiles works differently - how?

Comment: Did you try to put `combine.self="override"` on the profile `<configuration>` element, like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8119747/1743880)?

Comment: @Tunaki can try that, but I want to override the `<arguments>` tag, not whole configuration

Comment: I think it only works if it's added to this element.

Comment: @Tunaki: `Attribute 'combine.self' is not allowed to appear in element 'configuration'.`

Comment: Can you add the XML exactly as you have tried it?